# Installing ceiling tiles over insulation on the bottom of roof rafters in detached workshop

Tags: ceiling, workshop

I’m working on converting an old detached garage into a workshop. The roof rafters are 24”-ish OC.

I’m insulating between the rafters now (faced fiberglass) and an adding perpendicular furring strips to the bottom of the rafters to help support the insulation as I install and to provide a better nailing surface for whatever I end up covering the insulation with.

I want something fire rated over the insulation, but the garage is old and I’m concerned about the weight of drywall. I was considering just attaching Class A rated mineral fiber ceiling tiles to the furring strips. I know it’s a bit of a hack, but is there something I’m missing that would make this a terrible idea?

Comment: Can you take a picture or two of you rafters?  How deep are they (6", 8"), and what's the span between supports.

Comment: Make it less of a hack by using nail-up tiles designed for that application (which you'll want to pick before deciding on a furring spacing) rather than drop-ceiling panels screwed or nailed.

Comment: @SteveSh, I’ll see if I can grab some pictures, but it’s an old structure (so old the framing is all not nominal dimensions but actual and I’ve pulled several square nails from the structure). The rafters are 2x6’s. The spacing varies from as much as 30” to 14” and at least half of them aren’t square. I figure it’s lasted this long so it should be ok, but I don’t know if I should push it too much 

Comment: Since this is for fire safety, I would recommend sanity-checking whatever you choose with the Local Authority Having Jurisdiction (in the US, usually the town's building inspector's office) to make sure they will be happy with it. You don't want to put in all the work and then have them tell you to rip it out and redo it.

Answer (score 0):

If you left an air gap between the insulation and roof deck that part is good. It's a garage so the tiles would be ok. If the finished look is ok with you then you are good.

Comment: I installed 1” poly board with a 2” air gap between it and the underside of the roof (with ridge and soffit vents for airflow) and and sprayfoamed and caulked the edges to make it airtight. I was using batt insulation to help deaden sound (as well as being less flammable).